# Put node in promiscous mode

Tags: contiki

How do I capture all the packets in radio range of a particular node in contiki?

While reading the contiki mailing lists and contiki github, I could read people saying something about making changes to core/dev/cc2420.c file. Some people spoke about setting or resetting values of CC2420_CONF_AUTOACK.

I nowhere found proper information regarding putting a node in promiscous mode.  Please help.

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/dev/cc2420/cc2420.c). Maybe you should post a question on GitHub.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have tried my best to read the code for any scope to properly tweak it for desired purpose. On no progress, I thought of seeking help.
And I really don't know whether it is the correct file I should be making changes to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you mean to do is to disable the hardware address filtering. There is a radio API for this in Contiki:

```
#include "dev/radio.h"

// ...

radio_value_t radio_rx_mode;
if(NETSTACK_RADIO.get_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, &radio_rx_mode) == RADIO_RESULT_OK) {
   radio_rx_mode &= ~RADIO_RX_MODE_ADDRESS_FILTER;
   NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, radio_rx_mode);
}
```

You can also disable automatic acknowledgements by removing the `RADIO_RX_MODE_AUTOACK` bit of the `rx_mode`, but that's a different setting.

Comment: Please help me with where exactly to insert your piece of code.

Comment: Anywhere in your application's or protocol's code at the point where you want to start receiving all packets.